# Showing "Value Error: array is too big" error while making a contour plot from a big data file. How to fix?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, interpolation

I am trying to make a contour plot from a data file having four columns and 48000 rows (i.e. 48000 data points) using `matplotlib` using `Rbf` interpolation function of `scipy.interpolate` module. The 1st and 2nd columns are the two independent variables of the contour plot. The 3rd and the 4th column are two variables to be plotted in separate panels. The data file can be downloaded from the following link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2HPaW59cSeQbW9PYVBkTHdHTlk/view?usp=sharing

The code is as follows:

```
import numpy
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc, colorbar
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf

def forceAspect(ax,aspect=1):
    im = ax.get_images()
    extent =  im[0].get_extent()
    ax.set_aspect(abs((extent[1]-extent[0])/(extent[3]-extent[2]))/aspect)

# Import data:
x, y, z1, z2 = numpy.loadtxt("data_contourplot.dat",
usecols = (0,1, 2, 3),  unpack = True)

# Set up a regular grid of interpolation points
xi = numpy.linspace(min(x), max(x), 100)
yi = numpy.linspace(min(y), max(y), 100)
xi, yi = numpy.meshgrid(xi,yi)

rbf1 = Rbf(x, y, z1, function='linear')
rbf2 = Rbf(x, y, z2, function='linear')
z1i = rbf1(xi, yi)
z2i = rbf2(xi, yi)

fig1 = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 4), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
ax = plt.subplot(121)
cax = ax.imshow(z1i, vmin=z1.min(), vmax=z1.max(), origin='lower',
        extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])

#Function to adjust the layout of the plot
forceAspect(ay,aspect=1)

#plt.tight_layout()
fig1.colorbar(cay)
plt.show()
```

The error arises in the line of `Rbf` function calling as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "plot_contour_Ion_vs_delay_E_c.py", line 29, in <module>
rbf1 = Rbf(x, y, z1, function='linear')
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/rbf.py", line 185, in __init__
r = self._call_norm(self.xi, self.xi)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/rbf.py", line 207, in _call_norm
return self.norm(x1, x2)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/interpolate/rbf.py", line 107, in _euclidean_norm
return sqrt( ((x1 - x2)**2).sum(axis=0) )
ValueError: array is too big.
```

Please help me to fix this problem. Does `Rbf` function have some limitation on size to deal with. What is the standard practice of coding in `Python` to deal with big data files and contour plot or any 2D/3D plot in general?

Answer (score 0):

I used R-tree for interpolating only based of the current point region:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc, colorbar
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf
from rtree import index

def forceAspect(ax,aspect=1):
    im = ax.get_images()
    extent =  im[0].get_extent()
    ax.set_aspect(abs((extent[1]-extent[0])/(extent[3]-extent[2]))/aspect)


def norm(x1, x2):
    return ((x1 - x2)**2).sum(axis=0)

# Import data:
x, y, z1, z2 = np.loadtxt("data_contourplot.dat",
    usecols = (0, 1, 2, 3),  unpack = True)

idx = index.Index()
step_x = 0.1
step_y = 0.15
for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    idx.insert(i, (x[i] - step_x, y[i] - step_y, x[i] + step_x, y[i] + step_y))

# Set up a regular grid of interpolation points
xi = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 100)
yi = np.linspace(min(y), max(y), 100)
xi, yi = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)

flat_xi = xi.flat
flat_yi = yi.flat
z1i = np.zeros_like(flat_xi)
z2i = np.zeros_like(flat_xi)
for i, (xif, yif) in enumerate(zip(flat_xi, flat_yi)):
    ind = np.array(list(idx.intersection((xif - step_x*2, yif - step_y*2, xif + step_x*2, yif + step_y*2))))
    rbf1 = Rbf(x[ind], y[ind], z1[ind], function='linear')
    rbf2 = Rbf(x[ind], y[ind], z2[ind], function='linear')
    z1i[i] = rbf1(xif, yif)
    z2i[i] = rbf2(xif, yif)
    if i % 100 == 0:
        print(i)

z1i = np.resize(z1i, xi.shape)
z2i = np.resize(z2i, xi.shape)

fig1 = plt.figure(num=None, figsize=(8, 4), dpi=80, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
ax = plt.subplot(121)
cax = ax.imshow(z1i, vmin=z1.min(), vmax=z1.max(), origin='lower',
        extent=[x.min(), x.max(), y.min(), y.max()])

#Function to adjust the layout of the plot
forceAspect(ax,aspect=1)

#plt.tight_layout()
fig1.colorbar(cax)
plt.show()
```